# Subtract 6 months from current date in Spring query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have this query in Spring.

```
  Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT" +
    "  ips.*,
     "  FROM test1.ilist_property_summary ips " +
     "  WHERE (ips.statistics_date BETWEEN :currentDate AND :currentDate-6Months OR ips.statistics_date IS NULL)");
```

I need to pass two parameters: the first is `currentDate` and the second is the date of 6 months back from current date. For example:

> currentDate: 2017-10-13 00:00:00

and

> currentDate-6Months: 2017-04-13 00:00:00

How can I achieve this?

Comment: the query is "native" what kind of DB are you using? If mysql then DATE_ADD, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I am using mysql and JPA

Comment: DATEADD(MONTH, –6, GETDATE())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for.

```
 Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT" +
    "  ips.*,
     "  FROM test1.ilist_property_summary ips " +
     "  WHERE ( ips.statistics_date between date_sub(curdate(), interval 6 month) and curdate() OR ips.statistics_date IS NULL)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something likethis :

```
query.setParameter("currentDate",yourdtehere).getResultList(); //or singleResult
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to build date expressions, not pass parameters. Thanks anyway